# Defining a base class for custom exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Question:**

*What is the need to define a base class for handling errors?*

**Background:**

I was reading through the docs on [User-Defined Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) when I noticed in the example they defined `class Error(Exception)`. The remaining classes are all subclasses of it.

When I have been defining custom exceptions, I've simply written `class MyExc(Exception)` and never define a base class.

I don't understand, particularly in their example, the need for defining `class Error(Exception)` when all it does is pass. Yes they could just `raise Error` for a particular case, but couldn't they have just as well defined the two other exceptions as subclasses of `Exception` vice `Error`?

Comment: ... Because now you can catch `Error` instead of having to catch each individually.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Why define them individually if you wouldn't want to catch one specifically?

Comment: Sometimes you want to, sometimes you don't.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Hmm. That seems odd. You wouldn't `raise InputError("Hello", "World")` but `except Error` would you??

Comment: You rarely would. But that doesn't mean that you couldn't.

Comment: @datta You would. For example if you write any function that accepts another function as an argument. You usually wrap the call to the inner function with such excepts.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams In reference JonClements answer, even though a base class is defined, all the `except` clauses are declared. You comment "...instead of having to catch each individually" has me a tad confused; of course you must `except InputError` if you want to catch `raise InputError`! No?

Comment: Only if knowing that it's an `InputError` is important. Otherwise you can treat it just like a generic `Error`.

Answer (score 2):

When you write a library you usually define a base exception class for all your exceptions so that a user has a simple way to handle them all at the same time, e.g.

**MyLib**

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass
```

**some other code**

```
try:
   ...
except MyError:
   # MyLib error, handle it
```

But to be honest this "lib specific" handling hardly ever happens (usually you either catch a specific exception or just catch all `except Exception:`). So I guess it's not that important. More a matter of style.

Comment: If you're catching `Exception` then you're Doing It Wrong (unless it's your job, which it almost never is).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Lol, and why is that? Cause the internet says so? :D

Comment: Because it doesn't tell you anything about the exception, and it catches exceptions which aren't your responsibility.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It is my responsibility if it is my responsibility (e.g. when I write a web server framework). Posting such statements is pointless.

Comment: @freakish if you're catching blanket `Exception`s that have nothing to do with your framework and aren't re-raising them to something that can deal with them in context of the overall system, then yes - you're doing it wrong. If it's an exception you can deal with and sort out, then do so, otherwise, let it propagate until something else can.

Comment: @JonClements Of course it is not wrong. For example if I write a web server framework and don't catch an `Exception` at the top level it will crash. So instead you catch generic `Exception` and return 500 to the user. And log it in the meantime. Actually the same goes for **any** code that accepts a user defined function. Besides there's no such thing as `you're doing it wrong`. Everything has its place.

Comment: @freakish Sure - nothing wrong with that as you're telling the user "you don't handle this and I will" but as long as you can say using the framework, here's my exception handler, use that instead cos I don't want to display a 500 - I want to display a resource unavailable instead etc...

Comment: @JonClements Someone had to write this framework using `except Exception:` line, my friend. So don't say that "you're doing it wrong". You don't know the context, you don't know what code someone is writing. Such generic statements are simply wrong and confusing.